# How to get text between <input> and <br> using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to   get text between html tags instead of tags value.
For example: 
there is a tag

```
<input id="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle"  value="bike" >I have a bike <br>
```

i just need the text `I have a bike` instead of the `value="Bike"`.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waqasadil/7HQDK/59/)

Options Tag text is also not getting on the item list

Thanks In Advance for your kind help. Fiddle example will be appreciated.

Comment: input type checkbox does not hold text by surrounded tags. so you cant with this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this - to get the currently selected value:

```
var optionText = $('select :selected').val();
```

To get the currently selected text:

```
var optionText = $('select :selected').text();
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) return next sibling text of element.

```js
var text = $("#item")[0].nextSibling.textContent;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle"  value="bike" >I have a bike <br>
```

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HQDK/65/) for your code.

Comment: You are already using jquery. Why not using jquery [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) instead?

Comment: @AlexChar `.next()` select next element after input but question trying to get next text after input.

Comment: i want the option tag value in item list . 
when the user click on the any of the option tag the value between tags <option>Some value<option> should be copied to the item list .

Comment: @waqasadil You can find your answer using simple search. However i think you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/7HQDK/74/

Comment: @Muhammad : I need the option value in list order in item list

Answer (score 0):

***try this

add label or any tag for the content and get using ".next()" method.

```
$(this).next().html()
```

link : - http://jsfiddle.net/7HQDK/63/

***for option value to be printed in the list.

assign id to the select tag.

get the selected option value as :

```
$('#optionValue').find(":selected").text();
```

updated link :- http://jsfiddle.net/7HQDK/67/

***to print the option value only once in the list see the updated code in the link :

--add the following code after iteration and appending the check box values

```
list.append( "<li>" + optionvalue + "</li>" );
```

updated link :- http://jsfiddle.net/7HQDK/89/

Comment: Option tag value is not getting.

Comment: where do you want the option tag value? you didn't mention it.

Comment: i want the option tag value in item list

Comment: you have item as an id which should be unique. so change it. and how do you want the option value to be printed please let me know.

Comment: when the user click on the any of the option tag the value between tags <option>Some value<option> should be copied to the item list in Fiddle example.

Comment: how?? I have a car "space" volvo. likewise??

Comment: <li>Ihave a car <br> <li> volvo

Comment: I need Volvo in another list tag instead of same

Comment: I need it in the form of list instead of a single statement

Comment: dude what have you tried? i already said, you can print it however you want. but the technique to get the data to be printed is what i have showed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<span>` tag to wrap the text. Then use

```
 $(this).next().html()
```

to get the value.

Another note, `id` should be unique. That means you can only use one id name in a document. So I would suggest you to change `id` item and instead use class.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your fiddle.

First thing : Do not use the same ID for all your checkbox. That is considered as an error by a html validator.

Then, to do what you want easily, use labels for your checkboxes as follow :

```
<input id="item1" type="checkbox" name="vehicle"  value="bike"><label for="item1">I have a bike</label> 

<input id="item2" type="checkbox" name="vehicle"  value="bicycle"><label for="item2">I have a bicycle</label>
```

When you got that, you just have to change your `this.val()` by a selector which will get the html content of your label :

```
function addToList( values ) {
  var list = $( "#grocery-list ul" );
  list.empty();
  values.each(function(){
    list.append( "<li>" + $('label[for="' + this.id+ '"]').html() + "</li>" );
  });
```

};

Comment: You posted solution that another user said.

Comment: Yep, sorry for duplicate, when I started answering, only one answer was submitted.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="divTest">
        <b>Test</b>
        <input type="text" id="txtTest" name="txtTest" value="Input field" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
        alert("Text: " + $("#divTest").text());
        alert("HTML: " + $("#divTest").html());
        alert("Value: " + $("#divTest").val());

        alert("Text: " + $("#txtTest").text());
        alert("HTML: " + $("#txtTest").html());
        alert("Value: " + $("#txtTest").val());
});
</script>
```